# Unpivot using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i tried to unpivot a table with many columns (unknown number) into a table with four columns.

My query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO measurement (timestamp, sensor, value)
SELECT d."Timestamp", 
       ( SELECT s.id FROM sensor s WHERE s.name = columns.column_name),
       ( SELECT columns.column_name from sensor_list where "Timestamp" = d."Timestamp")     
FROM   sensor_list d, 
       (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'sensor_list' AND column_name <> 'Timestamp' ORDER BY ordinal_position) columns
```

This doesnt work. The Errormessage i receive is:

```
"ERROR: >>value<< has type numeric, but the expression is of type  information_schema.sql_identifier"
```

Is there any chance to get it work by converting `"columns.column_name"` to string or something else like with `quote_ident()` ?

All i tried did not work.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datatype of the column Value is numeric, the code will give error. Do you want to assign column name or column

Comment: I think i want to use column_name.

As sensor_list looks like: 
Timestamp | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | Sensor3 | ... | Sensor 999 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
time      | value   | value   | ...